# How come CSS backgrounds are intermittently invisible in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Here's a website I've designed:

- https://www.pensioenfondssdb.nl/

This is what it looks like in Firefox 4 beta 9 on Mac OS X 10.6.6:

- https://skitch.com/znerd/rkf67/schermafbeelding-2011-01-19-om-21.56.11

It looks similar in IE 8, Opera and Safari.

But this is what it looks like in Google Chrome 8.0.552.237 on Mac OS X 10.6.6:

- https://skitch.com/znerd/rkf9g/schermafbeelding-2011-01-19-om-21.52.11

Somehow most of the background images are gone. I checked with the Inspector, but the rules are there.

Sometimes Chrome does show the background images for a while and then after a while when I do a reload the images are gone. Odd.

Is this just me?

If not: What can I do to work around this issue?

Comment: just checked on my chrome and all is as should be, if it persists why not file a bug with chrome?http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Comment: FYI it looks fine on IE Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this same problem - posted about it here:
[backgound-image doesn't display intermittently. Google Chrome on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237860/backgound-image-doesnt-display-intermittently-google-chrome-on-mac)

I think it has to do with Chrome sometimes failing to cache the image properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at this in fiddler the first time I hit your site with chrome it only did the request for the page and didn't request the images.  The second time I got the 4-5 requests for the images.

Could you try and switch the page to http just for the moment to see if that changes anything?

Comment: I have created a bug report in Chromium, see: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70268