# backgound-image doesn't display intermittently. Google Chrome on Mac

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a website with a div for which I set the background-image to a random image:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #bighead {width:100%;height:500px;text-align:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;}
    <?php
    $bgImages = array('main-bg-1.jpg','main-bg-2.jpg','main-bg-3.jpg','main-bg-3.jpg');
    print '#bighead {background-image:url('.$bgImages[array_rand($bgImages)].');}';
    ?>
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=2e4402f4f417">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://beta.images.theglobeandmail.com/bundle/gzip_106019672/css/site.v3.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bighead">
    Nulla facilisi. In vel sem. Morbi id urna in diam dignissim feugiat.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm hosting this little example here: http://ryan.courtnage.ca/chrome-bg-bug/

Every time you reload the page, you will get a random background image. This works great in all browsers, with the exception of Chrome on Mac.

With Chrome on a Mac, the background image will display just fine, until you refresh a number of times. At a certain point, some of the background images will simply not display. It's intermittent.

I think it may have something to do with the browser's cache. If I clear Chrome's cache, and start refreshing the page, I'll see the following entries in Apache's access log:

```
xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [08/Mar/2011:19:53:40 +0000] "GET /chrome-bg-bug/main-bg-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 31821
xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [08/Mar/2011:19:53:52 +0000] "GET /chrome-bg-bug/main-bg-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [08/Mar/2011:19:53:52 +0000] "GET /chrome-bg-bug/main-bg-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [08/Mar/2011:19:54:06 +0000] "GET /chrome-bg-bug/main-bg-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

1. 200 OK is returned & the image is sent to the browser. The background image always seems to work.

   304 Not Modified is returned. The background image displayed.

   304 Not Modified is returned. The background image displayed.

   304 Not Modified is returned. In this case the background image did NOT display.

All subsequent requests for main-bg-2.jpg, which result in 304 Not Modified, will produce the problem where the background image does not show.

I've duplicated this problem on multiple Macs running Google Chrome. I should also mention another important point. I only seem to be able to duplicate the problem when there are sizeable stylesheet and/or js files being included in the page. So in my example above, I'm loading in jquery and stylesheets from a couple of websites (stackoverflow & globaeandmail). It doesn't need to be these particular files, nor do the files need to come from an external source (I originally ran into the problem where all stylesheet & js files are local).

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I might get around it?

Comment: Yes, I can only duplicate the problem in Google Chrome on a Mac (Chrome on Ubuntu is fine).

Comment: I deleted my comments because I really wasn't thinking ...

Comment: What OS are you running. I can NOT reproduce in 10.5.8 Intel/Mac. Loads images every time

Comment: 10.6.6 Intel/Mac. The guy to the left of me can duplicate it, the guy to the right cannot. [big sigh...]

Comment: UPDATE: I've just updated to Chrome 11.0.686.3 dev. My colleague, who was able to duplicate updated to Chrome 10.  Neither of us can duplicate the issue anymore! Someone fixed something!

Answer (score 0):

You can always try appending a *?something* to CSS files or images to always force the browser to reload it. I would change the PHP random array item to this:
`$bgImages[array_rand($bgImages)] . '?' . rand()` so the browser thinks the image is dynamic and will not cache it. You can also set Apache's cache control settings, but adding the query string is a little easier and won't affect the entire site.

Comment: Circumventing the browser's cache could be a last-resort workaround I suppose, although it would make me feel dirty...

Comment: Yeah I know, this is a hack. Curious though...have you tried this in Safari? Is this a bug in Webkit browsers?

Comment: Huh...this is a new one on me. Chrome sometimes has CSS hickups. Like I have been working on a web app with a basic CSS border. Sometimes Chrome will just not show the bottom border only.... Refresh or select the surround text then it does. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a couple of years but I ran into a similar situation with Chrome & Safari this week.

We wanted to add a 'processing' state to several buttons throughout our app, so we added a new CSS class that simply applied an animated GIF as a background image. We needed to ensure that the GIF was cached prior to clicking the button, so we tried a variety of pre-load techniques.

The simplest solution was to use CSS content property as described here: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/even-better-image-preloading-with-css2

Chrome & Safari were both sporadic - they would often treat the image as un-cached, even when we forced the pre-load image to always be visible. We could only consistently get a 304/not modified response after the GIF had been downloaded and displayed directly on the button element itself. This caused the animation to often never appear for some users, as the app would redirect to a new page before the GIF could be downloaded once again. Other browsers always treated the image as cached, and applied the animation immediately when clicked.

Our final fix was to apply the GIF as the background image of the button's default state, positioned outside its bounds. The 'processing' state then simply changed the position back to within the button's boundaries.

I feel like this is related to the original issue, and just wanted to share some pain.